# How to get iou of single class in keras semantic segmentation?

Tags: python, keras, metrics, image-segmentation

I am using the Image segmentation guide by [fchollet](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/) to perform semantic segmentation. I have attempted modifying the guide to suit my dataset by labelling the 8-bit img mask values into 1 and 2 like in the Oxford Pets dataset. (which will be subtracted to 0 and 1 in `class OxfordPets(keras.utils.Sequence):`)

**Question is how do I get the IoU metric of a single class** (e.g 1)?

I have tried different metrics suggested by Stack Overflow but most of suggest using MeanIoU which I tried but I have gotten **nan loss** as a result. Here is an example of a mask after using autocontrast.
`PIL.ImageOps.autocontrast(load_img(val_target_img_paths[i]))`
[image]

The model seems to train well but the accuracy was decreasing over time.

Also, can someone help **explain how the metric score can be calculated from `y_true` and `y_pred`?** I don't quite fully understand when the label value is used in the IoU metric calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem back then. I used `jaccard_distance_loss` and `dice_metric`. They are based on IoU. My task was a binary segmentation, so I guess you might have to modify the code in case you want to use it for a multi-label classification problem.

```
from keras import backend as K

def jaccard_distance_loss(y_true, y_pred, smooth=100):
    """
    Jaccard = (|X & Y|)/ (|X|+ |Y| - |X & Y|)
            = sum(|A*B|)/(sum(|A|)+sum(|B|)-sum(|A*B|))
    
    The jaccard distance loss is usefull for unbalanced datasets. This has been
    shifted so it converges on 0 and is smoothed to avoid exploding or disapearing
    gradient.
    
    Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index
    
    @url: https://gist.github.com/wassname/f1452b748efcbeb4cb9b1d059dce6f96
    @author: wassname
    """
    intersection = K.sum(K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1))
    sum_ = K.sum(K.sum(K.abs(y_true) + K.abs(y_pred), axis=-1))
    jac = (intersection + smooth) / (sum_ - intersection + smooth)
    return (1 - jac) * smooth

def dice_metric(y_pred, y_true):
    intersection = K.sum(K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1))
    union = K.sum(K.sum(K.abs(y_true) + K.abs(y_pred), axis=-1))
    # if y_pred.sum() == 0 and y_pred.sum() == 0:
    #     return 1.0

    return 2*intersection / union

# Example
size = 10

y_true = np.zeros(shape=(size,size))
y_true[3:6,3:6] = 1

y_pred = np.zeros(shape=(size,size))
y_pred[3:5,3:5] = 1

loss = jaccard_distance_loss(y_true,y_pred)

metric = dice_metric(y_pred,y_true)

print(f"loss: {loss}")
print(f"dice_metric: {metric}")
```

```
loss: 4.587155963302747
dice_metric: 0.6153846153846154
```

Comment: For your masks, did you use 0s and 1s for binary segmentation?

Comment: Yes, 1s were my foreground, and 0s background.

Comment: Did it help by the way? If it did, would be great to accept this answer to help other people.

Comment: Yes it did! I think there is something wrong with my dataset though because shuffling the dataset resulted in wildly different scores returned for jaccard_distance_loss. Additionally, the dice metric did not improve even after training it at a low learning rate of 1e-5.

Comment: I see. Be sure you normalize the dataset before feeding it to the model. Also FYI, my loss was around 5, and metric around 0.4, but the prediction on the test dataset was quite okay. In general, It is rather difficult to get high accuracy in semantic image segmentation, because the model predicts an image (e.g. 256×256 pixels), but not an instance (e.g. cat, dog). Good luck with your work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tf.keras.metrics.IoU` method, and you can find its documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/IoU

And how you can use it is shown here:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = [0, 1]
y_pred = [0.5, 1.0]  # they must be the same shape

# target_class_ids indicates the class/classes you want to calculate IoU on
loss = tf.keras.metrics.IoU(num_classes=2, target_class_ids=[1])
loss.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
print(loss.result().numpy())
```

And as you can see in the documentation, IoU is calculated by:

`true_positives / (true_positives + false_positives + false_negatives)`